# Difference in bitset<10> and bitset<2>(input[i]) , need explanation

Tags: c++, binary

I just learned some simple encryption today and wrote a simple program to convert my text to 10-bit binary. Im not sure if i'm doing it correctly, but the commented section of the code and the actual code has 2 different 10-bit outputs. I am confused. Can someone explain it to me in layman terms?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include "md5.h"

using namespace std;
using std::cout; 
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input ="";
    cout << "Please enter a string:\n>";
    getline(cin, input);

    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;
    cout << "md5 of " << input << ": " << md5("input") << endl;
    cout << "Binary is: ";
    // cout << bitset<10>(input[1]);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        cout << bitset<2>(input[i]);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of turning 8 bits into 2?

Comment: I'm actually trying to create a mini rainbow table of 1024 words. Converting it because 1024 is 2 to the power of 10. Is there any other better method for my reduction process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr : A char is 8 bits, and the string operator[] returns the different chars, as such you accessed different chars and took the first two bits of those. The solution comes in treating a char as exactly that: 8 bits. By doing some clever bit manipulation, we can achieve the desired effect.

### The problem

While I still have not completely understood, what you were trying to do, I can answer what a problem could be with this code:

By calling

```
cout<<bitset<10>(input[1]);
```

you are reading the 10 bits starting from the second character ( `input[0]` would start from the first character).

Now, the loop does something entirely different:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
cout << bitset<2>(input[i]);
```

It uses the i-th character of the string and constructs a bitset from it.

The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) of the bitset constructor tells us this means the char is converted to an unsigned long long, which is then converted to a bitset.

Okay, so let's see how that works with a simple input string like

```
std::string input = "aaaaa";
```

The first character of this string is 'a', which gives you the 8 bits of '01100001' (ASCII table), and thus the 10 bit bitset that is constructed from that turns out to print

```
0001100001
```

where we see a clear padding for the bits to the left (more significant).

On the other hand, if you go through the characters with your loop, you access each character and take only 2 of the bits.

In our case of the character 'a'='01100001', these bits are '01'. So then your program would output `01` five times.

Now, the way to fix it is to actually think more about the bits you are actually accessing.

### A possible solution

Do you want to get the first ten bits of the character string in any case?

In that case, you'd want to write something like:

```
std::bitset<10>(input[0]);
//Will pad the first two bits of the bitset as '0'
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
    char referenced = input[i/4];
    std::bitset<2>((referenced>>(6-(i%4)*2)));
}
```

The loop code was redesigned to read the whole string sequentially into 2 bit bitsets.
So since in a char there are 8 bits, we can read 4 of those sets out of a single char -> that is the reason for the "referenced".

The bitshift in the lower part of the loop makes it so it starts with a shift of 6, then 4, then 2, then 0, and then resets to 6 for the next char, etc...
(That way, we can extract the 2 relevant bits out of each 8bit char)

This type of loop will actually read through all parts of your string and do the correct constructions.

### A last remark

To construct a bitset directly from your string, you would have to use the raw memory in bits and from that construct the bitset.
You could construct 8 bit bitsets from each char and append those to each other, or create a string from each 8 bit bitset, concatenate those and then use the final string of 1 and 0 to construct a large bitset of arbitrary size.

I hope it helped.